# How to get the list of non-indexed columns of all tables of a DB?

Tags: mysql

I want to get the detailed list of non-indexed columns of entire tables of a DB.

Please help me how to get the list in MySQL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single table use:

```
show columns from tablename where `Key` is not null and `Key` != '';
```

For a whole schema/database use this:

```
select distinct
  table_name,
  index_name
from information_schema.statistics
where table_schema = 'your_database_name';
```

For all databases remove the where clause.

Described in the doc of [show columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html).

> The Key field indicates whether the column is indexed:
>
> If Key is empty, the column either is not indexed or is indexed only
>   as a secondary column in a multiple-column, nonunique index.

Comment: i want a single query to search for all tables in a database.